# Can't install package (Cinnamon)

Tags: 10.10, installation, apt, ppa, cinnamon

I am trying to install Cinnamon 1.4 on my Ubuntu VM (10.10) and I can not get this to work. If someone could be nice enough to explain what i'm doing wrong I would really appreciate it!

https://launchpad.net/~gwendal-lebihan-dev/+archive/cinnamon-stable

```
adam@ubuntu:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable
  Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /etc/apt/secring.gpg --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80/ --recv 109C2938F84496D6ACB6D805A777609328949509
  gpg: requesting key 28949509 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
  gpg: key 28949509: "Launchpad Gwendal Le Bihan" not changed
  gpg: Total number processed: 1
  gpg: unchanged: 1

adam@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get update
  W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

adam@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install cinnamon
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  E: Unable to locate package cinnamon
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cinnamon is not supported in ubuntu 10.10 ,so if you wanto install cinnamon you have to upgrade to ubuntu 11.10

Comment: Ooooooh. Man I am a dunce. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

First, that PPA is Only for Oneiric and second, i don't think cinnamon is supported in ubuntu so if you have problems with it when you try it out you are by yourself.

Comment: From the Cinnamon site, it says it supports it... however it's needs a repo, unlike Mint.

Comment: cinnamon is for gnome3, not gnome2